# Given $0<k<1$ and sequence $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le k*|a_n-a_{n-1}|$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ,Prove the sequence Convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Well I didn't find previous similar questions in the search and I'm stuck at this question.

Given $0<k<1$ and sequence $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le k*|a_n-a_{n-1}|$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ,Prove the sequence Convergent

I tried playing with the absolute values and show somehow its converges but no luck.

Comment: **Hint :** Prove the sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: Though about it but I'm not sure how to deal with it because the sequence require $a_{n+1}$ and not $a_m$

Comment: A little induction can give you an estimate of $|a_m-a_n|$...